# Add a soap header to soap envelope before sending it

Tags: java, soap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding custom Soap Header to Webservice Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022135/adding-custom-soap-header-to-webservice-request)

I am trying to call a web service with a java client generated from WSDL file. There is a requirement to add `<soap:Header>` inside `<soap:Envelope>`.
When I generated the client in eclipse and called the service, request message was,

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soap:Body>
      <tem:GetEntityXml>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:entityGuid>f949d2fe-d5a2-4115-a920-e85343adcf1a</tem:entityGuid>
      </tem:GetEntityXml>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Where as I want it this way,

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <wsa:Action>http://tempuri.org/xxx/HelloWorld</wsa:Action><wsa:To>https://xxx/yyy.svc</wsa:To>
</soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:GetEntityXml>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:entityGuid>f949d2fe-d5a2-4115-a920-e85343adcf1a</tem:entityGuid>
      </tem:GetEntityXml>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried to modify the SOAP envelope before the `_call.invoke()` method.

```
org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement she=new org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing",null); 
        she.addNamespaceDeclaration("wsa","http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");


        SOAPElement node=she.addChildElement("Action","wsa");
        node.addTextNode("http://tempuri.org/xxx/HelloWorld");
        System.out.println("2");
        SOAPElement node2=she.addChildElement("To","wsa");
        node2.addTextNode("https://xxx/yyy.svc");

        _call.getMessageContext().getCurrentMessage().getSOAPEnvelope().addHeader(she);;
        System.out.println(she);
        _call.addHeader(she);
```

As I am very new to web service things every suggestion is most welcome.

Please help me to create and format header as required.

Comment: see [SO ... adding-custom-soap-header-to-webservice-request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022135/adding-custom-soap-header-to-webservice-request)